# Python: stratified sampling on unbalanced data with ratio

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sampling

Here is my data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
                   'var2': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','c','d','d'],
                   'var3': ['y','y','y','y','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','q','q', 'r'],
                   'var4': [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

since var4 is unbalanced. I am planing to take each `var4 = 1` and twice amount of `var4 = 0` based on the group `var2` and `var3`. As a result, group 'a' 'y'  will have one '1' and two '0'; group 'b''r' will have two '1' and 4 '0'. Other groups will have none. Looks like the one below:

```
df_sampled = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11],
                   'var2': ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b'],
                   'var3': ['y','y','y','r','r','r','r','r','r'],
                   'var4': [0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]})
```

I tried to figure out the size of var4=1 per group:

```
df.var4 = df.var4.mask(df.var4.ne(1))
dd = df.groupby(['var2', 'var3']).var4.count().tolist()
```

I also tried using `sample()` to run on the list dd:

```
df.loc[df['var4'] == 0].groupby(['var2','var3'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(dd))
```

However,  it is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this way. Sort `df` to push all `1` to top. `cumcount` on groupby of `var1` and `var2` to use as a counter. Getting sum of each group (since `var4` values are only `0` and `1`, sum of each group is the number of `1` in each group). Finally, slice on rows where the the counter less than or equal twice of sum.

```
df = df.sort_values('var4', ascending=False)
gb = df.groupby(['var2', 'var3'])
s = gb.cumcount().add(1)
s1 = gb.var4.transform('sum')
df_final =  df[(s - s1) <= (s1 * 2)].sort_index()

Out[1758]:
   var1 var2 var3  var4
0     1    a    y     0
1     2    a    y     1
2     3    a    y     0
4     5    b    r     1
5     6    b    r     1
6     7    b    r     0
7     8    b    r     0
8     9    b    r     0
9    10    b    r     0
```